# Half year, half years, half a year?

Tags: determiners, grammatical-number

Which one is correct in English?

- *Half year*,
- *half years*, or
- *half a year*?

Example sentences, where `HY` is one of the above:

1. `HY` ago he had a job.
2. After `HY` he finally found a job.

Note, that *half year* vs. *half-year* can be answered from a [dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/half-year):

> Pre-tax profits in the *half year* surged to £73 million. (*Half year* is a noun.)
>
> The bank's *half-year* earnings rose 214% [...]. (*Half-year* is an adjective.)

Comment: Half a year is less than one  year, so why would you use the plural?

Comment: @KateBunting It is "0.5 years" and even "zero years", so that rule may need adjustment

Comment: @Henry, in my experience it should really be "0.5 *of a* year". You can leave out "of" when it is the word "half" or vulgar fraction 1/2. You would use the plural when it is more than 1. However more modern practice appears to be to use the plural for any decimal, including 1.0.

Comment: Please undo your downvotes. The question was edited since when you downvoted it. *Thanks for one person who did this already.*

Comment: You may have a hard time getting the attention of the people who already voted on your question with a comment. You could post on [meta] and ask people to take another look or give you feedback on how to earn their upvote.

Comment: Does that usually work? I don't see how it would improve the situation.

Answer (score 3):

[Half year](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/half-year) is correct. It is ****a*** half year*, or *half ***a*** year* so singular.

**Usage without the `a`**:

*The half year earnings of the company went up* (better written with a hyphen: *half-year*)

*The first half year of an infant's life...*

**Usage with an `a`**:

In the following sentences ***I*** would always use half ***a*** year; disclaimer: I am not a native English speaker

*Half a year ago something happened.*

*After half a year he finally found a job.*

Alternative is using *Six months ago...* which solves the issue of the `a`

Comment: "Half a year ago" is much better than "a half year ago". I would be inclined to use a hyphen for the latter, i.e. "a half-year ago. "Three half-years ago" makes sense, but "three half years ago" doesn't really.

Comment: I would ALWAYS use half a year ago until I read the [cambridge entry](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/half-year)